# Locate bookmarks folder after finding bookmarks in Firefox

Tags: firefox, search, bookmarks

When I search bookmarks I can't find a way to locate the folder of the result.

I have many bookmarks folder and subfolders and most folders and subfolders contain some bookmarks. When I cannot remember or guess the folder where a bookmark resides but I know I have it, I can search for bookmarks and all results are listed and I can click each result. There are properties of each result displayed. I would expect that the folder where a bookmark lives is an important property, but I cannot find this information.

Is this a one way street? Once you put it somewhere you have to always remember where you put it, otherwise no way to locate it? Is such a basic back reference missing in the Firefox bookmarks search?

*Edit:* In the meantime I found a related question (my question is also asked as a secondary question there), just for reference: [How to search for bookmark folders in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/22275/how-to-search-for-bookmark-folders-in-Firefox)

*Edit 2:* This was already filed as a bug: https://bugzilla.Mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196509 as pointed out by m_cowen_uk in his answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

White Alice0775 is your saviour, and helps a bit with [my problem](https://superuser.com/questions/22275/how-to-search-for-bookmark-folders-in-firefox/99254#99254).

[Show Parent Folder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7372) Add On works around bug 196509 - so it has already been reported.  I've also installed [Go Parent Folder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7377) to go with it.

Comment: Both _Show Parent Folder_ and _Go Parent Folder_ addons apparently have been removed by its author.

Answer (score 3):

Do your search.
Bookmarks.
Organize Bookmarks. 
Search Bookmarks.
Like You and other said there it is.
So double or single click (whichever) and go to the site.
Now right click the tab itself.
Click Bookmark this Tab.
Since you already have this Bookmark, the Edit this Bookmark window appears.
Name of Bookmark (website)
Folder (Name) What  your looking for.
There is (2) two drop down arrows next to the folder name.
Choose (click) the one furthest right.
Which now allows you to scroll down to the highlighted folder 
and information needed to say, THERE IT IS!
      I KNOW THIS WILL HELP
     ( konmaan )

Helpful Hint: open two browser windows, reading this one working on the other.

Comment: It's nice to know that trick, but it doesn't work if the target page has moved.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any way to show the folder in the search results - maybe there is an add-on that will do what you want...

Wondering why this hasn't occurred to me even though I like to keep my bookmarks organised, I think that when I look in the bookmark folders for a bookmark and can't find it, I use the organise bookmarks tool and just cut and paste it into a (hopefully more) sensible place. Where it comes from within the folder tree is irrelevant.

I don't actually use the bookmark folders very much any more - I tend to just type directly into the address bar and let Firefox search through its database...

Perhaps you should file a bug?

Answer (score 1):

This should work on pretty much all versions, without plugins, but will require some work on your end.

I had inadvertently dragged a bookmark folder into another.

First, `export` your bookmarks.

Current instructions are https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/export-firefox-bookmarks-to-backup-or-transfer  :

- Menu:  Bookmarks/Show All Bookmarks

[image]

Second, open the exported bookmark file with a text editor and search for the item of interest.

Currently Firefox exports to json format, but puts everything on one line.  In my case, I was able to use a Sublime Text, for which I have Prettify HTML, Javascript command that puts each bookmark on its own line and nests them.

In my screenshot you can also Export to HTML.  That might make be easier to search than the JSON option I picked.