# Find out in which folder particular bookmark is in Firefox

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Locate bookmarks folder after finding bookmarks in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/99223/locate-bookmarks-folder-after-finding-bookmarks-in-firefox)

In the **Firefox Library (Ctrl-Shift-B)**, I search my bookmarks. I find some and want to organize them - put them to some specific folder. But I don't see which folder they are in! I might have already sorted them placed different folder.

#### How can I find out in which folder the bookmarks I just filtered are?

(This is a real pain. I remember I was using Mozilla 10 years ago, before Firefox was born, and Mozilla was great - it could do this of course. Firefox has cut many useful features, trying to be more "modern" or "easier" for users, I don't clearly understand why... )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Show Parent Folder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/show-parent-folder/) is a Firefox extension which will let you see the parent folder when you search for a bookmark.  It only works when you're searching via the Library (i.e., "Show All Bookmarks") by adding "Parent Folder" to the "Views->Show Columns" list; it doesn't affect the sidebar search at all.

Comment: Drat. Doesn't seem to work in Firefox 33. [Go Parent Folder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/go-parent-folder/) does, though.

Comment: _Go Parent Folder_ has been removed as well.