# Searching for bookmark folder names in Firefox Quantum?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I have Firefox Quantum 57.0.2 (64-bit) in Windows 7.

In the Bookmarks list, unfortunately, I can search only for **bookmark names** but not for **bookmark folder names**!

I have a deeply nested bookmarks list with many folders and subfolders. I need to immediately find any subfolder by name and then look at all the bookmarks contained in this subfolder.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can vote for the Firefox bug here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=469441

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search for bookmark folders in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/22275/how-to-search-for-bookmark-folders-in-firefox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the "Bookmark Search Plus 2" add-on:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bookmark-search-plus-2/

It will add a button to toggle a bookmark toolbar (pretty much the same as the default one), where you can do your searches.
Among the results, folders matching the searched word will be shown as well.

As a plus, the search panel will be splitted in two, having the upper part showing the search results, and the lower part showing the selected result in the bookmark tree. This is very convenient when you have multiple bookmarks matching the same name.

Comment: Welcome on board, I would like to suggest that your answer must show those steps which could solve the issue. Since it's technical question !

Comment: You just have to install the plugin and search. I don't think it's really necessary to specify that. Anyway, I edited my answer with more details

Comment: Thank @Fed, I do believe that  properly elaborated  answer is a good practice. Have nice time :-)

Comment: Thanks @FedFranz, the extension is great, should be marked as an answer. And the answer is clear; no need to add anything else...

Answer (score 0):

You may try my add-on for this task -> https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/at-your-command/. For example query **b folder:add** will show only bookmarks whose parent folder name contains add. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJao5.png.